# Create list of runtime-known type from object list and call generic method

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, reflection

I have `IEnumerable<object>` in memory.

Let's say this:

```
IEnumerable<object>() addedEntities = // ... some Linq-To-Object query
```

Also, I have a method with this signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> FilterByUniqueProp<TSource>
                (this IEnumerable<TSource> query, TSource model)
{
       // Do something according to this type
       var type = model.GetType();
}
```

As you see, this is an extension method. So, I can't dynamically call it, I must use `MethodInfo` for executing it in runtime.

In runtime, I must dynamically call this method for some `Enumerable<T>` of **runtime-known** type. 
But, it didn't matter what I did, it doesn't work. Either `model.GetType()` is always `Object` or exception is thrown.

> Object of type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateEntry,System.Object]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PersonDetail]'.

Here what I had tried:

```
 IEnumerable<object>() addedEntities = // ... some Linq-To-Object query

 Type listType = typeof(List<>);
 Type constructed = listType.MakeGenericType(model.GetType());
 dynamic myList = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
 myList = addedEntities;

 MethodInfo mesthod = typeof(DynamicLinqExtensions).GetMethod("FilterByUniqueProp");
 MethodInfo genericMethod= mesthod.MakeGenericMethod(model.GetType());
 dynamic sameEntitiesInContext = genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { myList, model });
```

Comment: The types in the `IEnumerable<>` are all of a single type or multiple types? So are all `PersonDetail` or they could be one `PersonDetail` **plus** one `DogDetail`?

Comment: @xanatos All of single type.

Comment: Wait... You have the `model` object so you can check its type, right?

Comment: @xanatos Yes, right. I know what type of generic list I must create.

Comment: @farhas You don't even need to create a `List<>`. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy:

```
public static class DynamicLinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> FilterByUniqueProp<TSource>
            (this IEnumerable<TSource> query, TSource model)
    {
        // Do something accourding to this type
        var type = typeof(TSource);
        return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> FilterByUniqueProp2<TSource>
            (this IEnumerable<object> query, TSource model)
    {
        // We use Cast<>() to conver the IEnumerable<>
        return query.Cast<TSource>().FilterByUniqueProp<TSource>(model);
    }
}
```

You use `.Cast<>`!

Use it like:

```
// Your data
IEnumerable<object> addedEntities = new object[] { new MyClass(), new MyClass() };
object model = new MyClass();

// The needed code
Type type = model.GetType();

MethodInfo method = typeof(DynamicLinqExtensions)
          .GetMethod("FilterByUniqueProp2")
          .MakeGenericMethod(type);

method.Invoke(null, new object[] { addedEntities, model });
```

Note that in truth you could change directly the signature of `FilterByUniquePropr` to:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> FilterByUniqueProp<TSource>
        (this IEnumerable<object> query, TSource model)
{
    var query2 = query.Cast<TSource>();

    var type = typeof(TSource);

    return null;
}
```

and use reflection to call directl this method!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, it throws exception `Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev You forgot to put the `MakeGenericMethod()` somewhere

Comment: Thanks, it works. To tell the truth only thing I forget to use `Cast<TSource>` somehow. Thanks again.